# Rails and Postgres array columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a model with an array column (box_ids). In my view I would like to have a field for each of the values in the array and three extra empty fields to be able to add new values to the array. How to go about this? I have the following:

```
  <%= f.fields_for "box_ids[]", @shop do |bid| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= bid.label :box_id %> Box ID: <%= bid.text_field [WHAT HERE] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I don't know if this is the right approach but in any case I have no method to supply to text_field.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

This works:

```
  <% @shop.box_ids.each  do |bid| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :box_id %> Box ID: <%= text_field_tag "box_ids[]", bid %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% 3.times do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :box_id %> Box ID: <%= text_field_tag "box_ids[]" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

But that requires special handling in the controller - I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Yes - it is an ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

Comment: And bid.object is a Shop class.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%= f.fields_for "box_ids[]", @shop do |bid| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= bid.label :box_id %> Box ID: <%= bid.text_field :box_ids %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But that just gives: undefined method `1' for #<Shop:0x007faf763f3720>

Comment: That just gives me {1,2,3} in the text field.

Comment: try updating that single textbox value to {4,5,6} and save. check in DB if it works.

Comment: what is the special handling in the controller?

Comment: @shop.update won't work since the params[:shop][:box_ids] is some array of strings. And empty fields will be stored as zeros.